# how to control the sort order of shipping method's rates in the same carrier class?

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3.4, carrier, magento-shipping

I'm trying to build a custom carrier-class (shipping method) that display shipping methods based on time/date related third party API, I tried to find out a solution to sort the below options but I failed

Has anyone faced such an issue? How does Magento sort these options?

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks

[image: Shipping carrier - custom class - time related shipping]

adding code sample :

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            // get current quote id
            $quoteId = false;
            $items = $request->getAllItems();
            foreach ($items  as $item) {
                $quoteId = $item->getQuoteId();
                break;
            }
            /**  Quote $quote */
            $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
            $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $lat = (float) $shippingAddress->getData('latitude');
            $lng = (float) $shippingAddress->getData('longitude');
            if (!$lat || !$lng) {
                return false;
            }

            $isIn = $this->descartes->IsIn($lat, $lng);
            if (!$isIn) {
                // @todo handle logging here
                return false;
            }


            $shippingPrice = 10 ;
            $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
            $slotsData = $this->descartes->getAvailableSlots();
            $lockBelow = (int) $this->getConfigData('capacitylock');
            $i = 1;

            foreach ($slotsData as $date => $slots) {
                foreach ($slots as $time => $slot_info) {
                    $capacity = (int) $slot_info['available_capacity'];
                    $id = (int) $slot_info['id'];
                    if ($capacity <= 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    switch ($capacity) {

                        case $capacity > $lockBelow:
                            $i = sprintf('%02d', $i);
                            /** @var Method $rate */
                            $rate = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
                            $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
                            $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
                            $rate->setMethod($id);
                            $rate->setMethodTitle($date . "_" . $time);
                            $rate->setPrice($shippingPrice);
                            $rate->setCost($shippingPrice);
                            $rate->setSortOrder($i);
                            $result->append($rate);
                            break;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            return $result;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->manager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

sample slots API response :

```
array(2) {
  ["2020-05-13"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["2:00 PM-4:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(568)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(-1)
    }
    ["4:00 PM-6:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(570)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(24)
    }
    ["6:00 PM-8:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(555)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["8:00 PM-10:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(566)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["10:00 AM-11:59 AM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(482)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["10:00 PM-11:59 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(671)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["12:00 PM-2:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(678)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
  }
  ["2020-05-14"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["2:00 PM-4:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(568)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["4:00 PM-6:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(570)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["6:00 PM-8:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(555)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["8:00 PM-10:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(566)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["10:00 AM-11:59 AM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(482)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["10:00 PM-11:59 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(671)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
    ["12:00 PM-2:00 PM"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(678)
      ["available_capacity"]=>
      int(25)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that displays this, it may be that in the query you just have to put an 'order by' or just sort the table that contains this data.

Comment: There is no db queries , I'm using an api to get the time slots and the api return them sorted by date and time , I'm just looping throw them one by one and add them  as rate object to the  result object

Comment: As I remember magento sort the methods by price, but in your scenario all the returned methods have the same price. You should create your own sort option in the custom carrier class by the field you want (probably date).

Comment: @AdamS. what is the method/class should I implement ? can you please name it , is it in the core ?

Comment: Use jQuery , may be that will help.

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal , won't work , what if I'm using the rest API ? there must be a way in php

Comment: what array you are getting OR you are creating based on data which you are getting from API.

Comment: First need to see code how you create those shipping methods. Then I guess I can answer. But I need to see code, part where you set it, I guess it will be collectRates() ?

Comment: @GStrato I've added a sample code , thank you

Comment: Hi @tawfekov can u advise me on this 
 please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327438/magento-2-how-to-display-shipping-methods-sort-order-by-price-rate

Answer (score 3):

Ok, take a look here:

```
vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Rate/Result.php
```

There is function `sortRatesByPrice()`; 
This foreach puts all in array for sorting:

```
foreach ($this->_rates as $i => $rate) {
        $tmp[$i] = $rate->getPrice();
    }
```

If you change this `$rate->getPrice()` to `$rate->getMethodTitle()` it will sort by method title, that in your case is date and time. 
I haven't looked deeper, but you can try to do plugin here or overwrite with preference. Just try and see. I think you will manage how to sort now. 
That `sortRatesByPrice()` is called here `vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Rate/CarrierResult.php`, function `public function getAllRates()`.

Comment: I believe this is the right method to write a plugin after it and apply a custom order there , I'll try to work on an example after this weekend

Comment: This approach works i.e. `replacing $rate->getPrice()` with `$rate->getMethodTitle()`. It will then sort the rates by method title.

Comment: Hi KestutisK https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327438/magento-2-how-to-display-shipping-methods-sort-order-by-price can u advise me

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply sort first the array before your foreach using at least `asort()`

> [asort()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp) - sort associative arrays in ascending order:

```
asort($slotsData)  
foreach ($slotsData......){}
```

Comment: It won't help. Magento later do order of its own by price. See my answer.