# Magento 2 how to display shipping methods sort order by price?

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping, onepage-checkout, shipping-rates

Hi we would like to sort and display the shipping methods **by price Low to High** on checkout page.

For example:

```
$31.72  Express Saver Federal Express
$37.50  2 DayFederal Express
$80.47  Standard Overnight Federal Express
$87.77  Priority Overnight Federal Express
$5.00   Fixed Flat Rate
$5.00   Media Mail Select Shipping Method
$10.00  FedEx Home Delivery Select Shipping Method
```

Referring this plugin concept trying to change my output using plugin.
[Magento 2: Hide other shipping methods when free shipping is available](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103175/magento-2-hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available)

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Test\Plugin\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Session\Generic;


class ShippingMethodManagement {

    /**
     * @var Generic
    */
    private $coreSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $sessionManager
    */
    public function __construct(
        Generic $sessionManager
    ) {
        $this->coreSession = $sessionManager;    
    }

    public function afterEstimateByExtendedAddress($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
    {
        return $this->filterOutput($output);
    }
    public function afterEstimateByAddress($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
    {
        return $this->filterOutput($output);
    }
    public function afterEstimateByAddressId($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
    {
        return $this->filterOutput($output);
    }
    private function filterOutput($output)
    {
       //Here i would like to sort shipping methods by shipping amount
     
        $all = [];
        
            foreach ($output as $shippingMethod) {               

                $all[] = $shippingMethod;
            } 

            return $all;
        } 
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What magento2 version you using?

Comment: Magento 2.3.5 ee

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Because it should sort by price. `vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Rate/CarrierResult.php` here you find `getAllRates`. Try to add breakpoint here with xdebug and check what you get and what it does.

Answer (score 2):

The below logic works for me.

```
    <?php
    namespace Demo\Test\Plugin\Model;
    use Magento\Framework\Session\Generic;
    
    
    class ShippingMethodManagement {
    
        /**
         * @var Generic
        */
        private $coreSession;
    
        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $sessionManager
        */
        public function __construct(
            Generic $sessionManager
        ) {
            $this->coreSession = $sessionManager;    
        }
    
        public function afterEstimateByExtendedAddress($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
        {
            return $this->filterOutput($output);
        }
        public function afterEstimateByAddress($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
        {
            return $this->filterOutput($output);
        }
        public function afterEstimateByAddressId($shippingMethodManagement, $output)
        {
            return $this->filterOutput($output);
        }
        private function filterOutput($output)
        {
           //Here i would like to sort shipping methods by shipping amount
         
            $all = [];
            
                foreach ($output as $shippingMethod) {               
    
                    $all[$shippingMethod->getAmount()] = $shippingMethod;
                } 
                ksort($all);    
                return $all;
          } 
        
    }
```

Comment: Good catch @Black

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the shipping cost attribute would be called (you may need to debug) however assuming it is 'price' this should work. Add this above the return :

```
usort($all, function($a,$b){
     return $a->price > $b->price;
});
return $all;
```